# restarting master and slave machines without breaking master slave MySQL replication

Tags: mysql, replication, ubuntu

We need to resize the size (CPU and RAM) of two database servers having MySQL server 8: **master** and **slave**, but this operation implies that those machines will be **restarted**, And I think a restart of those machines might cause a **problem in replication** !

Is there a proper way to restart our machines without breaking the replication, Or I'm wrong about the fact that restarting the master and slave machines (OS) can break the replication ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stop and start master and slave in any order you want. It doesn't matter, master first or slave first - for both stop and start.

The only requirement is master's `expire_log_days` config option should be bigger than maintenance duration. Otherwise master on start will rotate its binlogs faster than slave get a sync. Keep in mind that this variable should be set statically in the `my.cnf` file, not dynamically via `SET GLOBAL expire_log_days = X;`

Comment: (See also `binlog_expire_logs_seconds`)

Comment: Thank you, i didn't mention that we have a cronjob that move binlogs from their location in the master , I have to stop this cronjob before, right ?

Comment: @HamzaAZIZ Right. You need exactly the same layout for master after restart at least until slave will be synced.